# Update WKWebView content by Swift failed in background thread

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, multithreading, wkwebview

I want to do the following:

- I click on a div element in WKWebView and send message to swift. - ***OK***
- Swift does the processing by http request to receive a json. - ***OK***
- Swift sends this json to javascript or swift changes the WKWebView DOM - ***FAILED***

My javascript function for send a message to Swift:

```
function clicar( id, categ ) {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsHandler.postMessage( "{ 'id' : "+id+", 'categ' : '" + categ + "' }" );
}
```

My Swift receive message and process http request:

```
extension FirstViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "jsHandler" {
             if let messageBody = message.body as? [String: Any], let id = messageBody["id"] as? Int {
                 self.getData( id )
             }
        }
}

func getData( id: Int ) {
    let url = URL( string: "http://192.168.1.11/inter/app/api/varModel/event.php?categ=" + String(id) )


    _ = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, req, error) in
        if req != nil {  }

        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [[String: Any]]

                var textJson = json...
                print( text )
                // until here OK

                // FAILED HERE
                self.wk.evaluateJavaScript("mountCateg( '\(textJson)' );", completionHandler: nil)
                } catch {
                print( erro as Any )
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Javascript manipulate DOM:

```
function mountCateg( data ) {
    let text = "";
    for ( let i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
        text += "<div class='itemCateg' i='"+data[i].id+"' o='"+data[i].idOrganizer+"'>";
        text +=     "<img class='imgEvento' src='http://192.168.1.11/inter/site/imgEvents/"+data[i].imagem+"'>";
        text +=     "<p class='diaEvento'>"+data[i].dataHora+"</p>";
        text +=     "<p class='nomeEvento'>"+data[i].nome+"</p>";
        text +=     "<p class='localEvento'>"+data[i].cidade+"/"+data[i].uf+"</p>";
        text += "</div>";
    }

    $('#listaEventos').html( text );
}
```

It give me this error:

[image]

How do I process DOM change by swift?

***----- EDIT -----***

I tried but the error persists.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.wk.evaluateJavaScript("mountCateg( '\(textJson)' );", completionHandler: nil)
}
```

I tried too:

```
extension FirstViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "jsHandler" {
             if let messageBody = message.body as? [String: Any], let id = messageBody["id"] as? Int {
                 self.getData( id )
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     self.wk.evaluateJavaScript("mountCateg( '\(textJson)' );", completionHandler: nil)
             }
        }
}
```

There was no error, but nothing happened either! Did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`URLSession.shared.dataTask` completion block does not run on the main thread. Just call `evaluateJavaScript` on the main thread to fix it:

```
func getData( id: Int ) {
    let url = URL( string: "http://192.168.1.11/inter/app/api/varModel/event.php?categ=" + String(id) )

    _ = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, req, error) in
        if req != nil {  }

        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [[String: Any]]

                var textJson = json...
                print( text )

                DispatchQueue.main.async { // call evaluateJavascript on the main thread
                    self.wk.evaluateJavaScript("mountCateg( '\(textJson)' );", completionHandler: nil)
                }
            } catch {
                print( erro as Any )
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: I did what you said @xius but still giving the same error. It says I can not modify the UI on another thread

Comment: Not sure whether you did it correctly. self.getData is asynchronous, so putting evaluateJavascript outside of it would not work.

Comment: To clarify: you did wrap the evaluateJavascript in the main.async as it is in the original implementation. There is no error about the UI on background thread, yet nothing is happening?

Comment: Hey @xius In the original implementation (before the edit) it gives the error that I mentioned. It says that it can not make change in the UI in background, but in the main thread. After the edit I removed the evaluateJavascript from getData and put after self.getData. He gives no error but nothing happens!

Comment: @Donadon At that time you don't have textJson ready, that might be an issue. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Donadon Yes. It's happening after textJson is retrieved. Does it work?